# PO Receipt Release via API doesn't behave properly after creating PO Receipt via API

Tags: acumatica

When I Release a Purchase Order Receipt via the PO Receipt Action menu in the UI vs. the PurchaseReceipt/ReleasePurchaseReceipt REST API call, it behaves differently. Here is a list of things that don't happen via API call, but do happen via UI...

- Receipt Line unit costs are not set
- INItemSite row isn't created
- ItemStats costs are not set
- INTran costs are not set
- GLTran amounts are not set
- Batch amount totals are not set

After further debugging, I realized that when I create a PO Receipt via UI, then release via API, all of the missing data I mentioned is not missing. However, if I create the PO receipt via API, then release via API, the problem I mention happens. Below is the JSON I use to create the PO receipt via API. Why does this cause a problem when releasing? Are there any values I'm not specifying maybe that are required for a Release to work properly? Note: the Usr* fields are custom fields, and I've extended the ReleasePurchaseReceipt endpoint to accept them.

```
{
  "BillDate": {
    "value": "2019-10-19T00:00:00-04:00"
  },
  "CashDiscount": {
    "value": 0
  },
  "CashDiscountDate": {
    "value": "2019-10-19T00:00:00-04:00"
  },
  "ControlAmount": {
    "value": 0
  },
  "ControlQty": {
    "value": 20
  },
  "CreateBill": {
    "value": false
  },
  "CurrencyID": {
    "value": "USD"
  },
  "Date": {
    "value": "2019-10-19T00:00:00-04:00"
  },
  "Details": [
    {
      "AccrualAccount": {
        "value": "2020"
      },
      "Amount": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "BaseReceiptQty": {
        "value": 20
      },
      "Branch": {
        "value": "ROYBAY"
      },
      "CompletePOLine": {
        "value": false
      },
      "DiscountAmount": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "DiscountPercent": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "InventoryID": {
        "value": "0037117"
      },
      "LineOrder": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "LineType": {
        "value": "Goods for IN"
      },
      "Location": {
        "value": "01P"
      },
      "LotSerialNbr": {},
      "ManualCost": {
        "value": false
      },
      "ManualDiscount": {
        "value": true
      },
      "OpenPOLineNbr": {
        "value": false
      },
      "OpenQty": {
        "value": 20
      },
      "OrderedQty": {
        "value": 40
      },
      "POLineNbr": {
        "value": "1"
      },
      "POOrderNbr": {
        "value": "009769"
      },
      "POOrderType": {
        "value": "RO"
      },
      "Project": {
        "value": "X"
      },
      "ReceiptQty": {
        "value": 20
      },
      "TaxCategory": {
        "value": "EXEMPT"
      },
      "TransactionDescription": {
        "value": "tony item 20191019d"
      },
      "UnitCost": {
        "value": "40.000000"
      },
      "UOM": {
        "value": "EACH"
      },
      "UsrPubPOKeyValues": {
        "value": "RO/RG009769"
      },
      "UsrPubPOLineKeyValues": {
        "value": "RO/RG009769/1"
      },
      "Warehouse": {
        "value": "002"
      },
      "UsrPubKeyValues": {
        "value": "RB003184/1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "DueDate": {
    "value": "2019-10-19T00:00:00-04:00"
  },
  "Hold": {
    "value": false
  },
  "LastModified": {
    "value": "2019-10-19T23:59:16"
  },
  "Location": {
    "value": "MAIN"
  },
  "PostPeriod": {
    "value": "102019"
  },
  "Status": {
    "value": "Released"
  },
  "Terms": {
    "value": "DUEUPON"
  },
  "TotalAmount": {
    "value": 0
  },
  "TotalQty": {
    "value": 20
  },
  "Type": {
    "value": "Receipt"
  },
  "VendorID": {
    "value": "ROYAL GROU"
  },
  "UsrPubKeyValues": {
    "value": "RT/RB003184"
  }
}
```

Acumatica 2017 R2, build 17.210.0034

**Update 10/21/19:** If I remove the custom fields from the JSON for creating the PO receipt via API, the API Release will work correctly and the data I mention no longer is missing. So, for some reason, including new custom fields in the creation of the receipt prevents the API release from working properly. Is this a known bug? Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

**Update 10/24/19:** 
I've now narrowed this down to be stock item related. My JSON for creating PO Receipts is exactly the same except for inventory id. One successfully updates IN and GL values, and the other doesn't when Released. Sample JSON included below. What could be the difference between my two stock items that would cause this?

```
{
"BillDate": {
"value": "2019-10-24T00:00:00-04:00"
},
"CashDiscount": {
"value": 0
},
"CashDiscountDate": {
"value": "2019-10-24T00:00:00-04:00"
},
"ControlAmount": {
"value": 0
},
"ControlQty": {
"value": 5
},
"CreateBill": {
"value": false
},
"CurrencyID": {
"value": "USD"
},
"Date": {
"value": "2019-10-24T00:00:00-04:00"
},
"Details": [
{
"AccrualAccount": {
"value": "2020"
},
"Amount": {
"value": 0
},
"BaseReceiptQty": {
"value": 5
},
"Branch": {
"value": "ROYBAY"
},
"CompletePOLine": {
"value": false
},
"DiscountAmount": {
"value": 0
},
"DiscountPercent": {
"value": 0
},
"InventoryID": {
"value": "0037144"
},
"LineOrder": {
"value": 1
},
"LineType": {
"value": "Goods for IN"
},
"Location": {
"value": "01P"
},
"LotSerialNbr": {},
"ManualCost": {
"value": false
},
"ManualDiscount": {
"value": true
},
"OpenPOLineNbr": {
"value": false
},
"OpenQty": {
"value": 5
},
"OrderedQty": {
"value": 10
},
"POLineNbr": {
"value": "1"
},
"POOrderNbr": {
"value": "009828"
},
"POOrderType": {
"value": "RO"
},
"Project": {
"value": "X"
},
"ReceiptQty": {
"value": 5
},
"TaxCategory": {
"value": "EXEMPT"
},
"TransactionDescription": {
"value": "tony item 20191024a"
},
"UnitCost": {
"value": "10.000000"
},
"UOM": {
"value": "EACH"
},
"UsrPubPOKeyValues": {
"value": "RO/RG009828"
},
"UsrPubPOLineKeyValues": {
"value": "RO/RG009828/1"
},
"Warehouse": {
"value": "002"
},
"UsrPubKeyValues": {
"value": "RB003229/1"
}
}
],
"DueDate": {
"value": "2019-10-24T00:00:00-04:00"
},
"Hold": {
"value": false
},
"LastModified": {
"value": "2019-10-24T12:32:07"
},
"Location": {
"value": "MAIN"
},
"PostPeriod": {
"value": "102019"
},
"Status": {
"value": "Released"
},
"Terms": {
"value": "DUEUPON"
},
"TotalAmount": {
"value": 0
},
"TotalQty": {
"value": 5
},
"Type": {
"value": "Receipt"
},
"VendorID": {
"value": "ROYAL GROU"
},
"UsrPubKeyValues": {
"value": "RT/RB003229"
}
}
```

Comment: I would create a support ticket with Acumatica. The problem you might have is 2017R2 I believe is no longer supported.

Comment: I have also created a ticket, but no solution yet.